# Detect touch outside of View

Tags: android, view, touch

I have a custom View and I wonder, is there any chace that I could detect if something outside of my View is clicked. It MUST be in the View class, or else it can not work as I intended it to!

Full file: https://github.com/Nicba1010/AndroidLibrary/blob/master/src/com/nicba1010/utils/views/PieChartView.java

OnTouchEvent(so you know I did something)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
        selected = null;
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    double deltaX = event.getX() - rect.width() / 2 - rect.left;
    double deltaY = -(event.getY() - rect.height() / 2 - rect.top);
    double fromMid = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    boolean inCircle = fromMid < (rectSelect.bottom / 2);
    if (inCircle) {
        double angleInDegrees = getPositionOnCircumference(deltaX, deltaY);
        float percentage = (float) (angleInDegrees / 360f);
        float totalPerc = 0;
        int index = -1, i = 0;
        for (PieChartSlice e : slices) {
            if (percentage > totalPerc) {
                index = i;
            } else if (percentage < totalPerc) {
                break;
            }
            totalPerc += e.getPercentage();
            i++;
        }
        if (index == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            final PieChartSlice tmp = slices.get(index);
            addScaleTask(rect, 500, 0.9f, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    selected = tmp;
                }
            });
            selected = slices.get(index);
            invalidate();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), selected.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onSliceSelectedListener.onSliceSelected(this, selected);
        }
    } else {
        if (selected != null) {
            addScaleTask(rect, 500, 1f, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    selected = null;
                }
            });
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Show some code of how you have it implemented! And why does it need to be inside your View class?

Comment: Because I am making a custom PieChart View and I want that when the View is defocused that the pie chart does sth, i cannot really explain, but that is the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Are you using Fragment or Activity? You could implement clicklistener(s) to other views that does not contain your View. And make those clicklistener(s) run a method in your View.

Comment: No, the View is a standalone thingy, I'm making some custom Views for myself.

Answer (score 3):

`View` has the `getHitRect(Rect)` method. You can use to retrieve it hit rect of this view and you can use this rect to check it the MotionEvent it is inside it. For instance

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
getHitRect(rect); 
if (rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()) {

}
```

Comment: But I can't detect a motion event from the entire screen inside of a view.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: use the code "getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)" instead "getHitRect(rect)"